# Crystal report operation not yet implemented error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, report

hay their i recently working on some *Inventory Management System* and i want to generate reports about daily reports. I use **MSSQL server 2008 R2** and **Visual Studio 2013** and **Crystal Report SAP** for *Visual Report.*

I have some stored procedure in the database that will give me the desired report using parameters. when  when i run the report by selecting a date from the *DateTime Picker* . it give the following error.

[image]

Comment: may be your stored procedure does not exist?

Comment: It does but finally it works with other approach. Thanks